# awk search for string and set exit code if it exists

Tags: awk

I want to check if a line exists between two addresses and return an exit code `0` if it exists and `1` if it does not. I think I've got one possible example working, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it; or perhaps a different tool that's also common on RedHat.

My Command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{found=1}NR==1,/^Match/{ if ( $0 == "PermitRootLogin yes" ) \
    { found=0 } }END { exit found }' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '/^PermitRootLogin yes$/{f=1} /^Match/{exit} END{exit !f}' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: Thanks, Works Perfect! If you could explain to me how this works I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If it finds the `Permit...` string it sets a flag `f` to say that. If it finds the `Match` then it stops reading the input file. When exiting the script it sets the exit status to 0 if the `f` flag was set, 1 otherwise. Note that `exit` in the main awk body means `take me to the END section` while `exit` in the END section means `quit the program with the specified exit status`.

Comment: Hi Ed.
Could you explain how stating `'!f'` gives me the correct exit code?
I don't understand the **negation** `!f` part. 
My example: `awk 'NR==6 && /due:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{f=1} END {exit !f}' $TODO ; echo $?
0`

Comment: @TonyBarganski Please read my comment immediately above yours. I don't know what else to say. If it's not clear than please just ask a new question. It won't be a duplicate if you word it correctly with sample input/output that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Please put the clarifications into the answer as it may benefit future users.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the explanation. Your solution works for me.
I would like to ask you how the awk command is returning the exit status = 1 when there is no match found.
So, what if when there is no string match (Permit...) does value of 'f' is set to 0 or 1?

Comment: Also, what is the significance of ^Match?
Is it something present in awk or you just took an example?

Comment: @LAKSHAYARORA `f=1` sets f to 1 when the match is found, and `exit !f` exits with 0 if f was 1 or 1 otherwise. See [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221262/awk-search-for-string-and-set-exit-code-if-it-exists/18221775?noredirect=1#comment26731157_18221775) and [this "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71868818/1745001) for more details on that. `^Match` is a regular expression to match the string `Match` at the start of a line because that's what the OP asked for. You can get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn awk.

Answer (score 0):

**Question**
@EdMorton
I was after clarification on the use of **'!f'** in your solution  and how this gives the correct exit 0 code? Specifically, what the **negation '!'** part is doing?

**UPDATE**
OK, I've finally wrapped my head around the exclamation mark on the awk exit code.

For anyone else out there for whom this wasn't immediately obvious too, the way to think of the exclamation point is not as a `negation` but as an **`invert`** function.

1. The truth is, gawk/awk returns EXIT_SUCCESS ('0') even if your regex does not match. Try it yourself. No match = no output but still shell exit code 0.

   Awk will however, perform a command based on whether the regex pattern is found or not, so we use that fact to perform a variable assignment (`'f=1'` in this case) if our conditions have been met. The conditions in my example below, are: - if NR is equal to line 6 AND the regex pattern is matched.
2. Here's the tricky part. Since EXIT_SUCCESS is a `'0'` for applications and we gave our flag variable **`f`** a numerical value of **`'1'`**, we need to **`invert`** this number with the exclamation mark in front of the exit variable **`!f`**. Now we get a `'0'` exit code from awk if our regex pattern was successful and a `'1'` exit code if it did not match.

One other observable truth worth mentioning here:

Awk's default action on a regex pattern *match* is to print the whole line matching the pattern. Once we tell awk to perform a task, like setting a flag `{f=1}` or giving the `{exit}` command, awk no longer prints the matched regex pattern to stdout.
Instead, awk now performs the task we told it to and quietly exits.

```
TODO=~/Dropbox/todo.txt
awk 'NR==6 && /due:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{exit;f=1} END {exit !f}'  \
$TODO ; echo $? 
0
```